# Sql Server database design issue

Tags: sql-server, database, database-design, foreign-key-relationship

I have an application with the following tables inside it.

```
Categories - CategoryID, CategoryName, CategoryTypeID, IsActive

CategoryTypes - CategoryTypeID, CategoryTypeName, IsActive

Items - ItemID, ItemName, CategoryID, UnitID, ItemPrice, IsActive

Units - UnitID, UnitName, IsActive
```

I have many tables, but I am not showing all of them because the if I got the scenario for one relation ship, I can do it for others.

here in above tables Item has a relationship with Categories with CategoryID (ForeignKey constraint)

Also Items has a relationship with Units (witn UnitID as the Fk constraint).

Now in my application, if I want to delete an Category which is referenced in Items table. I cannot delete Category if the referenced records in Items table are not deleted.

For that reason, I have to delete Items and then Category itself.

But the problem is if I delete Items - which I cannot delete because the ItemID in also being referenced in another tables called "OrderItems" and "Promotions".

here are the tables structures of those two tables.

```
OrderItems - OrderItemID, OrderID, ItemId, ItemQuantity, ... , IsActive
Promotions - PromotionID, ItemID,... IsActive
```

Now the actual problem occurs - If I want to delete an Category, I cannot delete unless and until I delete an Item.

If I want to delete an Item, all the reference tables that Item is pointing has to delete i.e means OrderItems and Promotions.

But as a business logic, I need the OrderItems and Promotions to be present even if the ItemID is not exists in the database (in Items table).

As there is a Foreign key constraint on Items with OrderItems and Promotions, I cannot achieve delete of Items record.

So, I would like to know - Can I make the foreign key as "Allow nulls" or simply drop the constraint and just use a normal tables (thinking that relation exists).

My one more constraint is if I tried to keep the data exits but making IsActive status to true or false (making IsActive to false if I want to delete a record). But the database will keep on grows and I think that is not the right approach.

I am really concerned about this problem as I am struck with the delete functionality of my application.

I hope you have understood my problem here.

Any help highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

personally I would recommend having a bit in the category table to set as inactive. I realize you do not like the idea of the database growing but if you want to insure referential integrity you should not delete primary keys that are in use.

If you need to delete them then you will want to run a procedure that will set the values in the item table to null and then delete them, making sure that you have set the item table CategoryID column to allow nulls.

**Edit:** additional information based on OP comment

Removing the foreign Key constraint is also an option. note though that there are two benefits  to having this constraint. The first should not apply too much to you but it involves speed. Foreign key constraints allow you cluster indexes on the column which will increase the speed at which you can access and join these rows. if your database is that small though, only a couple hundred megabytes you will likely not get a significant boost.

The other more important reason is because it insures the integrity of the database. While you can, and people do, manage the relationships yourself that does come with its own risks.  Remember you will need to write code in your business logic to check that a matching key exists, usually on insert and on access. For a small program this is fine but beware if you plan to expand as this can bite you later on.

Comment: Yes this is what I thought of doing, but it totally involves in the lot of re-work for me. So, is this would be the final approach making either "Allow Nulls" to these fields.

Comment: How about this approach - Removing constraints and thinking as a relationship exists. And now as there is no constraints existing, I can delete records easily without any updates to other tables but does this approach is the right way of doing? @KHeaney

Comment: And I have one more constraint is the data base size. I cannot keep the records in my database even if I am not going to use them. I have a very limited database size allowed for my application.

Comment: As my database is very small and I think the speed will not really matters. As my application will have an option to select an existing value (might be an Category in Items UI design or Items in OrderItems UI design). So, I am not at worried to cross check if that particular item is still exists or not. I am doing some R&D on this and it should not even effect my application when we do enhancing part also.

Comment: But if I am deleting a record (Say Items) and also at the same time removing constraint in OrderItems on Items table. So, what happens if I am deleting an Item and readding the same item. There will be a lot of mess going to happen. This is what so far I am thinking.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean but you should never delete and re-add an item. Writes are expensive operations to perform and if you are deleting something just to re-add it you are likely doing something wrong.

Comment: When user delete an Category with Name "ABC" and again adds the a Category with name "ABC". I think this will cause a problem @KHeaney like a lot of messup down the line, then I think, I have to add a Unique key constraint on it.

Comment: I do not understand why you think that. Quick Example: You work in the wedding industry and your DB starts with red (ID 1) in it. you clients say that nothing can be just red so you delete the red category and add carmine (ID 2) to replace it. Your clients find usability drops because no one knows to look under "C" for a red color so you delete carmine and re-add Red (ID 3). as far as the database is concerned Red (ID 3) is different from Red (ID 1) the association to any item is simply user generated.

Comment: You are saying, every thing is treated with the unique and primary key. So, why to bother about re-insertions. Am I right @Kheaney.

Comment: more or less. true people can get confused if they happen to remember that items use to have that association but nothing should prevent you from recreating it if needed

Answer (score 0):

Considered making a garbage category? Move items there and suppress is in all processing.

Alternatively allow Items to have no category (CategoryID = null) and thus update them to have no category.

Comment: Yes, I got this idea of making CategoryID in Items table as Allow Nulls. But is it the correct way to do? If I make CategoryID in Items table as "Allow Nulls". So, before delete a Category, I can update the column(CategoryID) in Items table to null and then I can delete Category. Am I right here @Tom Tom

Comment: Making one more table GarabageCategory and moving all deleted items. It's again the same thing like keeping all the data, but in a different table. Because just keeping Items (ItemId, ItemName) is not sufficient, if a record exists(think an Category or an Item) I might needs all the Item or Category details.